# C++ win32 thread createThread function not passing parameter correctly

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, winapi

So, I have been trying to figure out how c++ multi-threading works and how to apply it to the project I am working on. I am trying to accomplish creating a new thread and running a function on that thread. The function I am trying to run is called `SetupInfo` and takes an `Individual` as a single parameter. I have seen examples of this and have tried to implement them, but after multiple attempts I cannot successfully pass the parameter I need into the thread I want the function to run on. Here is what I have come up with:

Here I create a struct to store the pointer to the `Individual` that I need later on.

```
struct ThreadData
{
 Individual *m_pInd;
 ThreadData(Individual pInd) : m_pInd(*pInd) {}
};
```

Here I create a function that I can call in my program that creates the thread that runs the function `SetupThreadFunction` which takes a void pointer as a parameter. I am trying to pass the variable `data` into this function and then cast it back to `ThreadData` to be able to access the items of the struct.

```
void SetupThread(Individual input)
{
   ThreadData *data = new ThreadData(input);
   CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) SetupThreadFunction, data , 0, 0);
   delete data;
}
```

Here I create the function that is passed into the `CreateThread` function which takes a void pointer and casts it to `ThreadData` which can then theoretically access the `threadData->m_pInd`. The same pointer for `data` above is passed correctly into the `SetupThreadFunction`. However, `m_pInd` contains null data and not the pointer to the information that is expected. **Why is that?**

```
DWORD WINAPI SetupThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
 ThreadData* threadData = (ThreadData*)lpParameter;
 SetupInfo(threadData->m_pInd);
 return 0;
}
```

**Is there a more correct way to pass a parameter into the new win32 thread I am creating?**

Comment: *So, I have been trying to figure out how c++ multi-threading works*  -- I don't see how that first `struct` you posted is supposed to work, threads or no threads.  You take the address of the temporary parameter?

Comment: First issue, you shouldn't delete `data` in `SetupThread`. You should delete it after you've used it in `SetupThreadFunction`. Otherwise you've setup a dangling pointer. Bear in mind that `CreateThread` returns before `SetupThreadFunction` has finished executing (probably before it has started executing).

Comment: Also, why are you deleting the data, when the thread may still be running?  Multithreading is a lot more than calling `CreateThread`.  You need proper synchronization, and also maybe "Wait" for the thread to finish executing before you pull the plug on the data.

Comment: @PaulRooney yes it does. I have also tried removing the struct constructor and creating the struct using `ThreadData *data = new ThreadData();` and then giving it the value of the input `data->m_pInd = input;` but that has the same effect. Perhaps I am using the structure incorrectly?

Comment: @fudge22it What exactly is `Individual`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't think that the data mattered anymore since it had already been passed into the thread. Do you know of any good documentation where I could read up on win32 thread synchronization, etc?

Comment: `SetupThread` takes its argument by value. That means whatever is passed as `input` is copied when `SetupThread` is called and it ceases to exist when the function returns. If you take the address of `input`, you are taking the address of a temporary (I didnt see that that you even actually took the address). You must ensure it has a lifetime at least long as when `SetupThreadFunction` finishes executing

Comment: @fudge22it So you invalidated the data potentially before the thread has completed?  That is what the issue is.  Yes, you passed the data to the thread, but then the thread has to run.  So you delete the data that you passed, and now the running thread is now using bad data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie an Individual contains relative information of a person, including name, birth date, etc.

Comment: @fudge22it Then I don't see how in the world that struct compiled if an `Individual` hasn't got an overloaded `operator *`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, I just checked if commenting out that delete changes anything and the data in fact does get passed corectly. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Now I just need t figure out where the right place to delete the data will be.

Comment: @fudge22it There are `WaitFor...` functions provided by the Win API.  For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Things sure are a lot easier in the 21st century: [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct pattern is to allocate the object with `new`, fill in the data (if not done through parameters to `new`), pass the pointer to the newly-created thread, and let the thread `delete` the object when it's done with it. You `delete` the object before you know the thread has even started!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a multithreading problem; it's a pointer problem.

This line doesn't make sense to me:

```
ThreadData(Individual pInd) : m_pInd(*pInd) {}
```

`m_pInd` is a pointer and yet you're initializing it with `*pInd` which means you want to dereference `pInd`, but `pInd` is not a pointer, let alone a pointer to a pointer.  I don't see how this would even compile.

Assuming you actually meant `&` instead of `*`, as in:

```
ThreadData(Individual ind) : m_pInd(&ind) {}
```

The problem here is that you're creating a pointer to a copy of an `Individual` on the stack, and that copy goes away upon return from the constructor, so you have a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/).

```
void ThreadProc(Individual individual);

int main()
{
    Individual individual;
    std::thread thread(ThreadProc, individual);
    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `std:thread` compile with visual studios 2008? The code hasn't been updated to work for newer versions of visual studios, unfortunately limiting the tools I can use.

Comment: @fudge22it: `std::thread` was introduced in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: This solves the problem only if `Individual` is copyable.  If it isn't, then it suffers roughly from the same problem (or at least one of the same problems).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: But in that case, moving can still be an option.

Comment: @MSalters: Since fudge22it didn't show us anything about Individual, even after being asked for it in the comments, I have little confidence that it's moveable or copyable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code example to demonstrate the points already discussed.

```
#include "stdafx.h" // includes <windows.h>, <string> and <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

class Individual
{
public:
    string s;
};

struct ThreadData
{
    Individual *m_pInd;
    ThreadData(Individual* pInd) : m_pInd(pInd) {}
};

DWORD WINAPI SetupThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    cout << "Hi From Thread\n";
    ThreadData* threadData = static_cast<ThreadData*>(lpParameter);
    //SetupInfo(threadData->m_pInd);

    // do delete here, once its finished with.
    delete threadData;
    return 0;
}

HANDLE SetupThread(Individual* input)
{
    ThreadData *data = new ThreadData(input);
    return CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) SetupThreadFunction, data , 0, 0);   
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hi\n";
    Individual* i = new Individual;

    HANDLE h = SetupThread(i);

    if(h)   
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
        cout << "Done\n";
    } else
    {
        cout << "Couldnt create thread\n";
    }   

    getchar();

    delete i;

    return 0;
}
```

Bear in mind also you can use [`_beginthread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as a simpler interface to launch a thread on Win32.